# row count of columns with NUMBER datatype only using dynamic sql in oracle

Tags: oracle, count, dynamic-sql

I just did the count of rows only for every table in the schema.
Now I need the row count of columns in tables that have datatype NUMBER.
I don't know how to get the row count of individual NUMBER datatype columns of every table ?

```
DECLARE
  t_c1_tname user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
  t_command  VARCHAR2(200);
  row_count INTEGER;
  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT table_name FROM user_tables ORDER BY table_name;
BEGIN 
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
        FETCH c1 INTO t_c1_tname;
        EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
        t_command  := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t_c1_tname ;
        execute immediate t_command into  row_count;
        dbms_output.put_line('Table : '|| t_c1_tname || 'Count : '|| row`enter code here`_count);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Comment: select * from all_tab_columns where owner = 'H' and data_type = 'NUMBER';

Comment: Do you mean a count of non-null values in each number column, or the row count of any table that has any number columns? Also you can use `user_tab_columns` if you're only looking at your own schema; which using `user_tables` in your current code suggests.

Comment: select only those columns that have datatype NUMBER.
then do the row  count of NULL and Non_NULL values in that NUMERIC columns.
forgot to mention this part

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want, I think:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  not_null_count INTEGER;
  null_count INTEGER;
begin
  for r in (
    select utc.table_name, utc.column_name
    from user_tab_columns utc
    where data_type = 'NUMBER'
    order by utc.table_name, utc.column_id
  )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count("' || r.column_name || '"),
      count(nvl2("' || r.column_name || '", null, 1))
      from "' || r.table_name || '"'
    into not_null_count, null_count;
    dbms_output.put_line('Table: ' || r.table_name
      || ' column: ' || r.column_name
      || ' not-null: ' || not_null_count
      || ' null: ' || null_count);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

If I create some data:

```
create table t42(num1 number, num2 number, str1 varchar2(5));

insert into t42 values (1, 2, 'a');
insert into t42 values (3, 4, 'b');
insert into t42 values (5, null, 'c');
```

Then the block shows:

```
Table: T42 column: NUM1 not-null: 3 null: 0
Table: T42 column: NUM2 not-null: 2 null: 1
```

---

If you're querying `all_tab_columns` instead, you need to get and use the table owner:

```
  for r in (
    select atc.owner, atc.table_name, atc.column_name
    from all_tab_columns atc
    where data_type = 'NUMBER'
    order by atc.owner, atc.table_name, atc.column_id
  )
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count("' || r.column_name || '"),
      count(nvl2("' || r.column_name || '", null, 1))
      from '"' || r.owner || '"."' || r.table_name || '"'
    into not_null_count, null_count;
```

Comment: I used this code, works like a charm.
But I have a problem.

SELECT table_name, column_name
     FROM all_tab_columns 
     WHERE table_name IN ('tb1','tb2')
     AND data_type = 'NUMBER';

table1 is common to two schemas. So when I am running the above code with all_tab_columns, I am getting an error : table or view does not exist.

I don't know what is the reason ?

Comment: @Xasthur - if any table is not in your schema then you'd get that error; if a table appears twice and one of those is in your schema then you'd query the same one twice. You need to include the table owner in the dynamic SQL. I've updated the answer with an (untested, but I think I got the quotes right!) example.